# Get the tileset file names for TMXTiledMap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

What's the best way to retrieve an array containing the file names of the files used to load a certain `CCTMXTiledMap` ? I need to get the tileset file names because I want to dispose of them personally from the Cache in a future.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.2/interface_c_c_t_m_x_tiled_map.html#a0e4d5c1ec0940e6bc4dcc7a253af8da5) and [declaration](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.2/_c_c_t_m_x_tiled_map_8h_source.html) of `CCTMXTiledMap`, you'll want to walk the property `NSMutableArray* objectGroups`. Otherwise, you'll need to maintain your own data structure.

[This thread](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d) contains robust documentation and examples that should help you.

Comment: My deepest apologies. I formulated my question incorrectly. I didn't mean a tiled map object - I meant a tile map itself. As in, my tilemap uses three tileset files, I need to retrieve the names of those three files.

Comment: @Omega Oops! I believe [nycynik is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9916101/517815), then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the tmx file, it is an xml file, and search for 
it has a  tag with a source attribute.

```
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="sewer_tileset" tilewidth="24"
 tileheight="24">   <image source="sewer_tileset.png" trans="ff00ff"
 width="192" height="217"/>  </tileset>
```

you can parse the xml and just find all tileset->images.

You will need an xml parser if you want to do it on the phone, here is a good tutorial on that :http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project